# Ошибка в файле созданном через ShellExecute

Tags: lua

После создания файла через ShellExecute, в lua, через io.open, выводится данный результат: "��".
Если переместить данные из этого файла, в любой другой, все выводится верно.
В чем может быть проблема, какой-нибудь параметр?

Comment: *выводится данный результат* Выводится - где именно и как именно? *Если переместить данные из этого файла, в любой другой* Переместить - как именно? *все выводится верно* - опять же, где и как?

Comment: @Akina , результат выводится в игровую консоль. Через вызов функции print. Скопировать все данные и переместить в другой файл. ( dir path > output_path )

Comment: Значит, при запросе данных из этого файла для вывода его кодировка определяется/устанавливается неправильно. *Скопировать все данные и переместить в другой файл.* Как, чем? какой текстовый редактор используется? в какой кодировке сохраняется новый файл?

Comment: @Akina , работа с файлами производится в стандартном блокноте/sublime text. Если говорить конкретно, про копирование и перемещение: ctrl + a, ctrl + c, ctrl + v. Кодировка файла - UTF-8.

Comment: Как пример данных:    
Каталог: C:\Users\Lunatrius\Desktop\config


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
-a---        15.01.2021      0:13        158 11.lc                             
-a---        15.01.2021      0:33        161 11111.lc                          
-a---        15.01.2021     13:42        158 111111.lc                         
-a---        15.01.2021      0:13        172 default.lc

Comment: *Кодировка файла - UTF-8.* BOM? Просмотрите в хексах и исходный (который выводится криво). и копию (выводимую нормально) - в чём различие?

Comment: Я решил проблему, спасибо. Действительно проблема была в кодировке.
'-command "dir path | Out-File output_path -Encoding "ASCII"'